# How to renename an openpyxl book before write back

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

The problem is the following:

I'm loading an existing excel file as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook('template.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('template.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
```

Then I performe some modification to the file and I save it with

```
writer.save()
```

Since this procedure is a part of a bigger pipe, it would be beneficial to be able to rename the file `template.xlsx` before saving the modification. Is it possible?

Thanks in adavance for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just pass a new name to `pd.ExcelWriter(...)`?

```py
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook('template.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('foo.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book

writer.save()
```

Comment: Thanks @Justin for making me feel stupid :D

Comment: We've all had bad days.